# Retrieve all columns from one label in the top level alongside only a subset of another label

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3),
                   columns=list('abc'))
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((["df1"], df1.columns))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100, 112).reshape(4, 3),
                   columns=list('def'))
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((["df2"], df2.columns))
df = pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1)
```

It looks like

```
    df1         df2
    a   b   c   d   e   f
0   0   1   2   100 101 102
1   3   4   5   103 104 105
2   6   7   8   106 107 108
3   9   10  11  109 110 111
```

What is the most concise way to retrieve all columns of the first group and only a subset of the second group **without** calling `pd.concat()` or `df.drop()`? The result should look like

```
    df1         df2
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   2   100 101 
1   3   4   5   103 104 
2   6   7   8   106 107 
3   9   10  11  109 110
```

I tried a few variations along the lines of

```
df.loc[:, ['df1', ('df2', ['d', 'e'])]]
```

but all throw `NotImplementedError: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `concat` is simpliest way here, but it is possible e.g. if some way create masks and join them by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
m1 = df.columns.isin([('df2','d'), ('df2','e')]) 
m2 = df.columns.get_level_values(0) == 'df1'

df = df.loc[:, m1 | m2]
print (df)
  df1          df2     
    a   b   c    d    e
0   0   1   2  100  101
1   3   4   5  103  104
2   6   7   8  106  107
3   9  10  11  109  110
```

Or create tuples dynamic, e.g.:

```
L1 = df.columns[df.columns.get_level_values(0) == 'df1'].tolist()
L2 = [('df2','d'), ('df2','e')]

df = df[L1 + L2]
print (df)
  df1          df2     
    a   b   c    d    e
0   0   1   2  100  101
1   3   4   5  103  104
2   6   7   8  106  107
3   9  10  11  109  110
```